# What does this timestamp mean

Tags: php, time, timestamp, google-api

So I got a timestamp from Google API in the following format:

```
2012-08-21T20:19:08.452Z
```

My question is...What is that .452 preceding the Z? I believe Z denotes Zulu time aka UTC, but what is that .452....Are those fractions of a second?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7244246/generate-an-rfc-3339-timestamp-similar-to-google-tasks-api

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, those are fractions of a second. That is the ISO 8601 date format, by the way (specifically, the RFC 3339 subset of it).

If you want to convert it to a Unix timestamp, you can use PHP's [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) function (since you tagged this question `php`).

Comment: Aww rats, you beat me to the answer by literally a *fraction of a second* (pun intended) :( +1