# What is datetime object in Google API, and how to format its string output?

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-api-js-client

```
 "start": {
"date": date,
"dateTime": datetime,
"timeZone": string
}...
```

This is from the resource representations of Google Calendar API Events class(?). The `dateTime` field is supposedly a `datetime` object. I could not find any resources regarding this class or any of its functions, nor did I find a way to easily format its string output like for `Date` object.

Thank you!

[EDIT]From [How to convert date in RFC 3339 to the javascript date object(milliseconds since 1970)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11318634/how-to-convert-date-in-rfc-3339-to-the-javascript-date-objectmilliseconds-since) it looks like DateTime RFC 3339 string can be parsed into a `Date` object, which should solve the problem.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/49765656/9337071 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/7244246/9337071 for Tasks API datetimes (not quite Calendar, but another Google API)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the [Google Calendar resource documentation](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events), the datetime is an [RFC3339](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3339)-formatted string, e.g.

`"1985-04-12T23:20:50.52Z"`

In fact, it looks like the Google Java client library  has a built-in RFC3339 formatter to make this easier. See this answer: [How do I parse RFC 3339 datetimes with Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6038136/how-do-i-parse-rfc-3339-datetimes-with-java/41569330)

Comment: "Google Java client library" - the question is tagged [tag:javascript] (which has about as much in common with Java as Carpet does with Car).

Comment: @Quentin I'm aware, but the body of the original question says Java: "...Date class from Java". May have been a tagging error.

Comment: @Quentin Yes I intended to ask about Javascript, but maybe `Date` class from Java is a bad example. `Date` object in Javascript is much easier to format, but `DateTime` does not seem to share any similarity with it.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you've already got this sorted out but I just want to share my solution here in case someone else finds this useful.

Adding dateTime to the Google Calendar API seems to be most easily achieved by manipulating a Date object until it represents the appropriate date/time and only then calling the .toISOString() method on it to convert it into the format required by the Google Calendar API

also for the reference [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) is a list of timezones I found helpful

```
let startDateTime = new Date();

let finishDateTime = new Date();
finishDateTime.setTime(finishDateTime.getTime() + (1*60*60*1000));

const event = {
    'summary': 'test event',
    'start': {
        'dateTime': startDateTime.toISOString(),
        'timeZone': 'Australia/Melbourne'
    },
    'end': {
        'dateTime': finishDateTime.toISOString(),
        'timeZone': 'Australia/Melbourne'
    }
};

const request = gapi.client.calendar.events.insert({
    'calendarId': 'primary',
    'resource': event
});

request.execute(function(event) {
    console.log('Event created: ' + event.htmlLink);
});
```